# Replace Tags in Email Template

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to replace tags within a component. So, given the following text...

```
*|FIRSTNAME|*,

*|LINK|*

You can sign in with your email address (*|EMAIL|*)
Your password is:
*|PASSWORD|*

Thanks!

*|SIGNATURE|*
```

and this:

```
export default class Template extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    this.setState({
      mergeTags: {
        '*|FIRSTNAME|*': 'John',
        '*|LINK|*': 'www.test.com',
        '*|EMAIL|*': 'email@email.com',
        '*|PASSWORD|*': 'supersecurepassword',
        '*|SIGNATURE|*': 'Bob Law's Law Blog'
      }
    })
  }
```

I want to display, in a live preview window that updates as the user types, this:

```
John,

www.test.com

You can sign in with your email address (email@email.com)
Your password is:
supersecurepassword

Thanks!

Bob Law's Law Blog
```

Comment: Is the template text (the one with tags) hardcoded as HTML in the component?  Or is it passed down as pure text as a prop?

Comment: I posted an answer making some assumptions about how your code looks. Did it solve anything? If not, then maybe you can provide some more details about how your Template component look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know your exact setup, but this, or something like it, should work.
**JSFiddle demo** here: https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/zrrfyxh7/

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        '*|FIRSTNAME|*': 'John',
      '*|LINK|*': 'www.test.com',
      '*|EMAIL|*': 'email@email.com',
      '*|PASSWORD|*': 'supersecurepassword',
      '*|SIGNATURE|*': "Bob Law's Law Blog"
    };
  }
  // use componentDidMount, or else the ref thing below won't work.
  componentDidMount() {
    let innerText = this.templateElement.innerHTML;
    // loop through all the properties / "tags"
    for(let tagKey in this.state) {
        // replace the occurence of the tag key string, with the tag value in this.state
        innerText = innerText.replace(tagKey, this.state[tagKey])
    }
    this.templateElement.innerHTML = innerText;

  }
  render() {
    // get a reference to the element that contains the raw template
    return <p ref={ template => this.templateElement = template }>
      *|FIRSTNAME|*,
      *|LINK|*

      You can sign in with your email address (*|EMAIL|*)
      Your password is:
      *|PASSWORD|*

      Thanks!

      *|SIGNATURE|*
    </p>;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps. Tell me if anything is unclear.

**Edit**: Added a more React-like example, where the template isn't pure text, but HTML. **JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/539g38kc/

Comment: Thanks for your response! Users actually need to be able to customize and get a real-time example of the text. So, it's a customizable text field with a live preview window below it. Messing with it currently so I'll update if I make some progress.

Comment: No problem. I edited my answer and added another example for how it can  be done if the template doesn't have to be pure text with those tags (if it's defined more like HTML instead). The new example is more like how a typical React component would work, and is very much suited for the use case you described.